# What webhook event should I listen for when a recurring payment has been made

Tags: php, paypal, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using Paypal's REST-API to create billing agreements.

It's rather convoluted surrounding recurring payments and I need to discover which webhook event I should be listening for when a recurring payment has been made as at that point I need to increment the amount of days left a respective account has.

Reference: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/event-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name I was looking for was `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` to make sure it's from a Billing Agreement for recurring payments check for the existence of `billing_agreement_id`

eg

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$data = $data['resource'];

if (!array_key_exists('billing_agreement_id', $data)) {
    // Not a payment for a billing agreement
    // handle single payments or:
    die();
}
```

Comment: I am getting always webhook verification failure on sandbox, any clue why ?

Comment: Because paypal docs say that you cannot verify webhook events on sandbox? Literally says it on the webhook simulator you use: Because these are mock events, you cannot verify, resend an event notification for, or show webhook details for simulator-generated events.

Comment: I think there is a bug with PHP REST SDK, I tried same request with cURL and it works.

Comment: The REST SDK is sloppy, and neglected. They have breaking issues aged well over 6 months, paypal team is pathetic

Comment: Is it documented anywhere in the docs? I figured it out by test and error.

Answer (score 0):

The event name for recurring payment should be PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED .